# Append text to document.getElementById().value;

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, getelementbyid

I have a function:

```
function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    ...
}
```

And a form:

```
<form onsubmit="calcRoute(); return false">
<input type="text" id="start" name="start">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Users use the input to set an address in a city (always the same city). The problem is that 90% of the times the users only type the address (without ", Cityname" at the end). So sometimes if the streetname is present in other cities it can be confusing (and Google Maps may pick the wrong ciy). What's the cleanest way to append an "hardcoded" city name to the address typed by the users? Is it possible to use the form (plain html) to do this? If not, JS is ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate the string if there is no "Cityname" presented in the string:

```
function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    if (start.indexOf("Cityname") === -1) {
        start += ", Cityname";
    }
    // ...
}
```